# Javascript concat() not working as it should be

Tags: javascript, concatenation, typeerror

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var objDate = new Date();
    var hours = objDate.getHours();
    var mins = objDate.getMinutes();
    var time = hours.concat(mins);
    window.alert(time);
    if (time>=1600&&time<=0900) {
        document.body.style.background ="url('closed.png') no-repeat";
    } else if (time>=1230&&time<=1315) {
        document.body.style.background ="url('lunch.png') no-repeat";
    } else {
        document.body.style.background ="url('open.png') no-repeat";        
    }
}
setInterval(myFunction, 3000);
</script>
</html>
```

At line 8 
"var time = hours.concat(mins);"
I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" and it refuses to continue. All I want to do is specify if its between a certain time then we are open, closed or at lunch. Schedule never really changes so it doesn't need to be more advanced than that.

Comment: Is there a way to get both the hours and minutes in one to verify the time or is there no "simple" way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getHours()` returns a number so it doesn't have a `concat` method, so your script should throw an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
function myFunction() {
    var objDate = new Date();
    var hours = objDate.getHours()+'';
    var mins = objDate.getMinutes();
    var time = hours.concat(mins); //or hours + ':' + mins 
    window.alert(time);
}
setInterval(myFunction, 3000);
```

---

But for your calculation related to background style, it will be better to use time in minutes

```
function myFunction() {
    var objDate = new Date();
    var hours = objDate.getHours();
    var mins = objDate.getMinutes();
    var time = hours * 60 + mins;

    if (time >= 960 || time <= 540) {
        document.body.style.background = "url('closed.png') no-repeat";
    } else if (time >= 750 && time <= 795) {
        document.body.style.background = "url('lunch.png') no-repeat";
    } else {
        document.body.style.background = "url('open.png') no-repeat";
    }
}
setInterval(myFunction, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This actually makes more sense than what I was thinking of doing.

Answer (score 2):

concat() is for joining two arrays. You just want to join two strings. Try

```
var time = hours.toString() + mins.toString();
```